# Cant auto-attacks crit?

Tags: steam-monster-game

One of the upgrades available in the game is "Lucky Shot" - increasing `critical hit click damage`. One of the items, `Crit`, similarly increases the `chance to do critical click damage`.

Does Auto-fire canon constitute as click? Can it do critical damage, and if so is it modified by that skill? Are those worth investing in if I don't really plan to click on the monsters manually to deal damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The game makes the distinction between clicks and auto-firing. Clicks must come from an actual mouse click. This is to entice people to actively play the game as you're doing more damage that way.